# View message that was shared on facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to see what people are sharing from my app.  Using Facebook Insights, I can see

http://cl.ly/image/473J1z2M2L0F

Is there any way to see the content that was actually shared?  ie. what the person posted, and who it was that posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think there is a way, because it´s kind of a privacy issue to read user generated content. See here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

The only thing you get after posting is the post id (see "Return Data"), you could get the content with a graph api call, but it will not succeed because you would need access to the user feed. So the user would have to be logged in and you would have to track the shares by yourself...